# Something I don't quite understand about Conditional Mappings

Tags: entity-framework

In most cases, we can map a field in a table either to a property or we can map it using conditional mapping, but not both. Only exception is if condition is set to `Is NotNull`, since then we can also map to a column.

a) Is this the reason why we are able to map a DB column only once - namely, if field was allowed to have both a property mapping and a conditional mapping, then property mapping would tell EF to retrieve all table rows, while conditional mapping would tell EF to retrieve only those rows that satisfy the condition?!

b) If my reasoning under *a)* is correct, then why is field allowed to have both mappings when condition is set to `Is NotNull`? Why won't that create a conflict?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping with condition Is NotNull has special meaning because it requires subsequent change in your model. The mapped property in the model must not be nullable. So your column in the database is nullable, your mapping condition filters all records with null value and your property always receives only records with non-null values. Also you can never assign null to the property.

In case of common condition with value equality this special behaviour is not possible.

Comment: hi Ladislav. please forgive my stupidness, but I didn't find ( in your reply ) any answers to my two questions. If there is an answer lurking in your reply, could you please reword it ( aka dumb it down )?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I'm able to rephrase it to make it more clear. Just try to play with `Is NotNull` condition and map the related column as well and you should see the difference. There cannot be a conflict when using NotNull condition because the property in entity mustn't be nullable so conditional mapping is first level of filtering and any query filtering on the mapped property is just additional condition which cannot conflict with NotNull.

Comment: "...and any query filtering on the mapped property is just additional condition which cannot conflict with NotNull." shouldn't we by that logic also be allowed to map to a column when Is Null condition is used?

Comment: If your first condition (in mapping) allows only `Is Null` then any other condition except `Is Null` again doesn't make sense because it will filter out all records.

Comment: oh, I get it - while you can do further filtering on non-nullable properties/fields, you can't do any further filtering ( besides filtering on Is Null ) on properties/field that have a Null value. Much appreciated